# Packaging Chrome extension with a sidebar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sidebar

I'm trying to create an install package of my extension. It uses chrome.experimental.sidebar API. When I create the package and install it, everything works just after teh install. When I restart Chrome I cannot open the sidebar - it doesn't show. The onclick method works - I've added an alert to show at the end of it.

I turned on using experimental API in chrome://flags. When I use the extension installed in a folder everything works great.

Am I doing something wrong or does Chrome disallow using expermiental API from packages?

Comment: Check error console, is there anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you include the manifest file that you're using? Chrome has a [known bug](http://crbug.com/86449) where an empty manifest value (e.g. `"sidebar" : {}`) will not be preserved across restarts. Adding a dummy value inside the `sidebar` dictionary should prevent this.

Comment: Nice one. *(damn 15 char limit...)*